# How to get basic Hair setting

Tags: particles, hair

I want to know the setting for Hair Particles. I have my system i5 with 8GB RAM and 2 GB Graphic card. With the default sphere 1000 count and in the children 500 count my system get slows or hang i can't work on it. Is there any setting from start hair count to children setting, Thickness : hair root and tip setting to have a normal Human Hair. Im not asking about the shape or style. When ever increase the hair count get some clumps. Just the hair setting to have a good and natural look and my system also don't get hang can work freely. Any suggestion or reference video. Thanks.

[image]